# What is the best adjective to describe a well received product (movie, book)

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, articles

Often I read about "under-appreciated" books. Being an author myself, I am putting together my resume in English and I am unsure what word to use to describe a book that has had positive reviews and apparently was sucessful.   Should I say "appreciated book dealing with.."?
Also do I need to use articles?

> Title of the book
>    (An) appreciated book dealing ..

Comment: Many terms, the best depending on the circumstances: "commended", "well-received". Look up some book reviews. You'll find a wealth of such adjectives applied to a poverty of good books.

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to specify how many copies were sold (if it was successful) and who reviewed the book quoting his review, which would be more objective. Putting just one adjective or phrase before *book* doesn't sound like a good idea, especially in your resume.

Comment: *Most critics reviewed the book [favo(u)rably](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/favorably)*

Answer (score 5):

I think ***[well-received](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Well-received)*** is a good expression for your context:

> - having been greeted or reviewed with approval:
>
>   - *his well-received books.*

Collins Dictionary

Comment: This is a great term because it is not too powerful or overly expressive.

Answer (score 5):

Critically acclaimed book dealing ...

> acclaimed
>
> praise enthusiastically and publicly.
> "the conference was acclaimed as a considerable success"
> synonyms:   praise, applaud, cheer, commend, approve, welcome, pay tribute to, speak highly of, eulogize, compliment, celebrate, sing the praises of, rave about, heap praise on/upon, wax lyrical about, lionize, exalt, admire, hail, extol, honor, hymn;

[google](https://www.google.com/search?q=acclaimed&oq=acclaimed&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **succès d'estime**, e.g. "a succès d'estime dealing with ...".

> Definition: something (as a work of art) that wins critical respect
>   but not popular success; a success in terms of critical appreciation,
>   as opposed to popularity or commercial gain.
>
> Example: *Ted Turner founded CNN and built it into a succès d'estime
>   in global broadcasting, as well as a multi-million dollar business*.

Comment: I have never heard this term before. If I had seen it in print I would have had to look it up to know what it meant and how to pronounce it, and now that I know it I doubt I will ever use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think *renowned* might work:

> **renowned** (*adj.*) known or talked about by many people; famous

So, in your résumé:

> ***Chamber of Twilight***
>   *This renowned book deals with the forbidden love between a wizard and a werewolf*...

That said, I'm not sure if *renowned* is what you want, if you are talking about an "underappreciated" work. If not, you might try ***hidden gem***:

> *This hidden gem deals with the forbidden love between...*

Answer (score 0):

I often hear people talk about a particular work being "sensational." As in "[Title] was an overnight sensation dealing with..." This is a very strong term that far exceeds the term in your original post 'appreciated.'

This term should not be confused with 'sensation fiction.'

Comment: I would hesitate to use the word *especially* in my resume.